# how to center a form using css?

Tags: javascript, css, centering

Literally centering on ALL four sides. I see lots of tutorials just using

```
element.style.margin = "0 auto";
```

This only centers it on the X-Axis, but not the Y-axis.

How do I get it to center via Y-Axis as well?

Comment: There are a thousand questions floating around on vertically centering  a block element with CSS. It is not easy, but discussed several times. If you are using Javascript anyways for this, you could simply do some calculations with heights, and center it yourself (not leave it to CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used:

```
#myItem {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: -50px;
}
```

.... before, hope it helps

Comment: for me, it kinda moves it like 66% top and left.

Comment: I believe you have to substitute margin-top and margin-left's values to be half the height and width of your element, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on the element you want vertically centered and set `display: table` on its parent container element you want it centered inside of.